# How to find my private key! Please help!

Tags: private-key, private-key-export

Trying to send some BTC payments and don’t know my private key. Can anyone help me and tell me it or tell me how to get it.

Comment: which wallet are you using?

Comment: Blockchain wallet

Comment: Offering payment for answers is generally not okay on Stack Exchange.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160944/how-to-handle-question-offering-payment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to recover private key?,](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84215/i-need-to-recover-private-key)

Answer (score 1):

If you never had the private key for the bitcoin account you are trying to use, then you can't just recover or "find" it.
This is one-way algorithm: private key -> public key. You can get public from private, but not another way around.

Comment: Isn’t there sites where you pay like 0.03 and you can search any wallets address private key?? Or is that a total scam?

Comment: It's a scam. If the site could find the private key for any account, they would be rich by guessing the keys for known accounts with a lot of bitcoins. It will take millions of years to brute-force it.